# Strange behavior of auto completion when double tab in terminal

Tags: linux, autocomplete

I installed the new version of Ubuntu-12, and found a very strange auto-completion behavior.

For instance, I have a folder tree something like ~/A/B/C.eps

and open a terminal, under folder A, when I type 'display', and then double click tab key, and it used to be

~/A: display [double-tab]

~/A: display B/

But now it is

~/A: display B[a space here]

A space is followed up, not a forward slash.

This is very annoying, because, in the former case, I can double-tab again to enter display B/C.eps, which is very convenient, but now, I cant.

Could anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: So auto-complete is adding a space, not a trailing slash?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at /etc/bash_completion. I imagine your problem is in the _cd() function. Can't really help on the specifics unless you post yours.

In my case (LMDE), completion works as you describe. You can have a look at my default /etc/bash_completion [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14062712/bash_completion). Try comparing it to yours, or just replacing yours with this one.

Comment: Thanks, but what if it is not cd command, if the problem happens to other commands like "display", where should I modify?

Comment: Don't really know, you'll have to check the file. Try making a backup of your /etc/bash_completion and then replacing it with mine. Then open a new bash (either a new terminal, or run `source /etc/bash_completion` or just run `bash`) and see if that solves your problem.